# Two properties about Bessel function

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, improper-integrals, mathematical-physics

Let $J_\nu(x)$ be the Bessel function of the first kind.

1. $\int_0^\infty J_\nu(x)dx=1 , (Re(\nu)>-1)$.
2. $\lim_{\nu\to+\infty}J_\nu(x)=0$ for any fixed $x$.

I think the above two properties of Bessel function is correct. For 1, It is easy to prove when $\nu$ is an integer. However, I have no idea of proving it for any $\nu$.